# Button Crashes App When Touched In Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I made a button called `playAgainButton`, which is a button that allows the Tic Tac Toe game reset so you can play again...but this `playAgainButton` is crashing my app, instead of reseting the game to the default `gameState`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //All the odd numbers will be noughts & even will be crosses
    var goNumber = 1
    var winner = 0

    //0 = empty, 1 = nought, 2 = cross
    var gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    let winningCombinations = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]

    @IBOutlet weak var button0: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playAgain: UIButton!

    @IBAction func playAgainButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        goNumber = 1

        winner = 0

        gameState = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

        label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x - 400, label.center.y)

        playAgain.alpha = 0

        var button : UIButton

        for var i  = 0; i < 9; i++ {

        button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

        button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)

        }

    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        var image = UIImage()

        if (gameState[sender.tag] == 0) && winner == 0 {

        println(sender.tag)

        if (goNumber % 2 == 0 ) {

        image = UIImage(named: "cross.png")!
            gameState[sender.tag] = 2
        } else {

        image = UIImage(named: "nought.png")!
            gameState[sender.tag] = 1
        }

            for combination in winningCombinations {

                if (gameState[combination[0]] == gameState[combination[1]] && gameState[combination[1]] == gameState[combination[2]]) && gameState[combination[0]] != 0{

                    winner = gameState[combination[0]]
                }

            }

            if (winner != 0) {

                println("We have a winner")

                if (winner == 1) {

                    label.text = "Noughts has won"
                    label.backgroundColor = UIColor .blueColor()
                } else {
                    label.text = "Crosses has won"
                    label.backgroundColor = UIColor .blueColor()
                }

                UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                    self.label.center = CGPointMake(self.label.center.x + 400, self.label.center.y)

                    self.playAgain.alpha = 1
                })
            }

        goNumber++
        sender.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x - 400, label.center.y)
        playAgain.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

[image: Where the crash appears]

[image: Error message]

Comment: may be this can help you....`var button : UIButton?
        
        for var i  = 0; i < 9; i++ {
            
            button!.viewWithTag(i)
            
            button!.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
            
        }`

Comment: I changed it to exactly how you have it and I get the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: use `var button : UIButton?
        for var i = 0; i < 9; i++ {
            if let btn = button!.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton{
                btn.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }` and tell me if there is crash...and @Nicolas instruction is right

Comment: `Thread: 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` and i'm still receiving the `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Answer (score 0):

This simply means the the view returned by `viewWithTag()` is not an instance of `UIButton`, but just an `UIView`. The forced cast is failing at runtime, and that throws an exception.

I'm not sure what is returned when multiple views have the same tag, but make sure you are not assigning the same tag to another, non-button view somewhere.

Comment: I thought that's what the `as! UIButton` did, changing it to a UIButton.

Comment: No, casting only means interpreting a reference as a different type. It does not change the type of the actual, referenced object. You can not automagically convert a generic UIView into a specific UIButton: the superclass does NOT include the functionality of the base class.

Comment: It only works if the referenced object was a UIButton instance all along, referenced through a (generic) UIView reference (which is what viewWithTag() can return).

Comment: You are better _attempting_ to cast with an "if let" construct and "as?", and detect the error if the cast fails. That will not crash.

Answer (score 0):

The default value for the tag property is 0. your loops start from i = 0 as tag search that explain you error since in this case you get the first view that is not a button
Also use introspection to be sure of the view type it its a button

```
if object is UIButton {
    // object is of type UIButton
} else {
    // object is not of type UIButton
}
```

Comment: None of the button have the same tag.

Comment: however using button = view.viewWithTag(i) when i=0 it will always find a view  since the default value for the tag property is 0.  skip the 0 value in your loop

Comment: Even when I put `i = 1` I still get the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`